# value of text filed will display the dynamically div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My web page has a text field in which when you enter 0 the Add button is disabled. When more than 0 is entered the button should enable and it should display "hello" below the text filed the number of times of the value entered. For example, enter 2 the word "hello" should be displayed 2 times same for 3.

Here's my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "0";
  $scope.ash = "";
  var x = angular.element(document.getElementById("xyz"));
  $scope.hello = function() {
    $scope.name = x.val();
    $scope.ash = ['ashish'];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.name; i++) {
      alert($scope.ash);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="$scope.name">
  <input id="xyz" type="text" value="" ng-model="name" />
  <button ng-click="hello()" ng-disabled="name == 0">Add</button>
  <p ng-model="abc" ng-repeat="x in $scope.ash">hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please refer the link https://jsfiddle.net/r5z8Lhjs/3/

Comment: Please look into docs on stackverflow and learn to make proper format of questions

Comment: hi Anil,
I have already shared the fiddler link can u go through them and help me to resolve the issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/r5z8Lhjs/3/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the behavior. Your code is set up that when your textbox value is not 0 it enables the button. And then when you click the button it alerts the name(s) in your scope array.

Comment: Hi Ryan,
Thanks, u r reply but the issue is that I don't want to alert my requirement is it should print below the textbox like.
Hello
Hello

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

1. add `id` to `button` to be able find it in JS.
2. find element after what you want to add `hello`:

   ```
   var button = angular.element(document.getElementById('button'));
   ```
3. add `hello` after that element `i` times:

   ```
   button.after('<p>hello</p>');
   ```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "0";
    $scope.ash = "";
    var x = angular.element(document.getElementById("xyz"));
    $scope.hello = function() {
        $scope.name = x.val();
        $scope.ash = ['ashish'];
        var button = angular.element(document.getElementById('button'));
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.name; i++) {
            button.after('<p>hello</p>');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="$scope.name">
  <input  id="xyz" type="text" value="" ng-model="name"/>
  <button ng-click="hello()"  ng-disabled="name == 0" id="button">Add</button>
</div>
```